# git reset commit_id with trailing dot not working via JGIT

Tags: jgit, git-reset, git-revert

I created git repo with three commits:

```
commit 99c3de6f701ed9e60d8a2fa0f7c435bc738685dc (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
    added c

commit 6a2e2b1fcb6cf54bb001c7f8618b623b10974cc2
    added b

commit e68e2a7e491a627e52d3ba83027897f800344843
    added a
```

In git shell `git reset e68e2a7e491a627e52d3ba83027897f800344843 -- .` resets the repository to the first commit and keeps all history and HEAD point to MASTER at the third commit.

I've tried to develop the same command using JGIT:

```
ResetCommand reset = git.reset();
reset.setRef("e68e2a7e491a627e52d3ba83027897f800344843");
reset.addPath(".");
reset.call();
```

But JGIT command has different behavior - it resets MASTER to the first commit and some history lost:

```
commit e68e2a7e491a627e52d3ba83027897f800344843 (HEAD -> master)
    added a
```

Is it a bug or I should design JGIT reset command another way to get required behavior?

Comment: The `git reset` form that uses pathnames is an index-oriented operation only (vs the `git reset` form that *doesn't* use pathnames, which updates the stored hash ID in the current branch) so it probably has an entirely different JGit method. But I don't "do" JGit so I can't tell you which one.

Comment: Shouldn't your first command be `git checkout e68e2a7 -- .`? `git reset` resets the index entries, not the work tree.